# DFT of a unit step

Tags: dft

Studying DSP on my own.

Intuitively I understand that DFT of unit step is $\delta[n]$ , but I can't demonstrate it mathematically. Here is what I have so far

$$
DFT\{u[n]\} = X_k = <\textbf w^{(k)}, \textbf u> = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\overline {w^{(k)}}[n]u[n] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\overline {e^{j \frac{2 \pi}{N}kn}}u[n] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{-j \frac{2 \pi}{N}kn}u[n] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{-j \frac{2 \pi}{N}kn}
$$

Using the formula for geometric progression,

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} ar^k = \frac{a(1-r^{n+1})}{1-r}
$$

In my case $a = 1$ and $r=e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}k} $, so

$$
X_k = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{-j \frac{2 \pi}{N}kn} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left(e^{-j \frac{2 \pi}{N}k}\right)^n = \frac{1-e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}kN}}{1-e^{-j \frac{2 \pi}{N}k}} = \frac{1-e^{-j2\pi k}}{1-e^{-j \frac{2 \pi}{N}k}}$$

It looks like $X_k$ for $k = 0$ is not even defined. I have a feeling I've done something wrong, but I quite can't figure it out. Have rechecked calculations several times and can't find any issues.

Would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: i think you have more fundamental problems stemming from how to relate the DFT to the Fourier transform of non-repeating signals like the unit step.

Comment: you need to get the part of the unit step that is equal to zero represented in this problem

Comment: Note (as hinted at by Robert) that this is just the DFT of a *constant* signal. There's no step involved anywhere. If you wanted a step you would need to choose your DFT window symmetrically around $n=0$ to get zero values for negative $n$ and unity values for $n\ge 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ok! The line you have found just reads like this:

$$
X_k = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{-j \frac{2 \pi}{N}kn} = \frac{1-e^{-j2\pi k}}{1-e^{-j \frac{2 \pi}{N}k}} = \begin{cases} N &, \text{ for } k=0 \\ 0 &, \text{ for } k \neq 0 \\ \end{cases} = N\cdot\delta[k]$$ for $k=0,1,...,N-1$.

How to arrive the conclusion? The most elementary treatment is to pre-set the value of $k=0$ into the summation before using the formula for the sum, hence avoid the undefined $0/0$.

Comment: tiny tiny tiny thing: shouldn't it be $N$ for $k=0$, according to the sum over all $N$ instances of $e^0$?

Comment: yes it should be... thanks! now I can go to sleep... :-)

Comment: and $$X_{k+N}=X_k \qquad \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$$ so it's periodic in $k$ with period $N$.  so it is really equal to $$N \cdot \sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta[k +mN]$$

Comment: @Fat32 Can you clarify how did you get from $ \frac{1 - e^{-j 2 \pi k} }{1- e^{-j \frac{2 \pi}{N}k } } $ to $ \begin{cases} N &, \text{ for } k=0 \\ 0 &, \text{ for } k \neq 0 \\ \end{cases} $. Because when I substitute $0$ for $k$ I get the following $ \frac{1 - e^{-j 2 \pi 0} }{1- e^{-j \frac{2 \pi}{N}0 } } = \frac{1-e^0}{1-e^0} = \frac{1-1}{1-1} = \frac{0}{0} = undefined$. What am I missing?

Comment: @Fat32 Let me clarify again. I think I understand, how to get a value of $N$ from the equation. But I can't figure out how to get a $0$. Can you clarify?

Comment: @flashburn: $e^{-j2\pi k}=1$ for any integer $k$.

Comment: @flashburn: I'm pretty sure that Fat32 means that 1) for the k = 0 case, do the sum directly without using the closed form solution. 2) for k doesn't equal zero case, use the closed form solution. but I'm confident that he will confirm. interesting question.

Comment: @flashburn as markleeds commented, for k=0 you use the sum of ones and for k nonzero use the formula. k nonzero the formuls is: $$ \frac{ 1 - e^{-j 2 \pi k} } { 1 - e^{-j 2 \pi k / N} } = \frac{1 - 1} {1  - r} = \frac{0}{1-r} = 0 $$ I hope you can see why $e^{ -j 2 \pi k} = 1$ for all k and $e^{ -j 2 \pi k /N} = 1$ only for $k = 0,\pm N, \pm 2N,....$  And also as Robert commented, the actual result is a **periodic** impulse train. rather than a single impulse. In genereal we shall consider only those values of $k$ in the range $k=0,1,...,N-1$.

Comment: @Fat32 I almost got it. But, shouldn't closed form solution as well as the sum formula work whether $k=0$ or $k \neq 0$? So the question is, how do I make it work independently of the form of the solution?

Comment: @flashburn. You are right. If you want to make the closed form (geometric sum formula) to be used for all **k** then for $k=0$ as you get $0/0$, you should apply L'Hopital's rule to get rid of $0/0$. Then it will be ok. But some people object to such a trick to be applied for discrete-time sequences hence they prefer the more algebraic version.